# can't resize containers with youtube and responsive

Tags: html, css, youtube, containers

http://m.mits.remax.ca/
The above link, there's a huge gap between the youtube and the header.  I tried looking everywhere and still couldn't find what went wrong.

At first, I used regular youtube `iframe` and centered the video but I found out it's not responsive that way so I found some online css and added it which worked fine but I tried making the video 75% instead of 100% but with 75% the gap happened.

Can someone give me a hand please?

the css I found and used is

```
.video-container {
        position: relative;
        padding-bottom: 56.25%;
        padding-top: 25px;
        height: 0;
    }

    .video-container iframe,
    .video-container object,
    .video-container embed {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 12.5%;
        width: 75%!important;
        height: 75%!important;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`height: 75%;` in your video that causing a huge gap between the video and header. You can adjust that, e.g: `100%`. If you want to adjust the height, don't set the video height to `75%` but set the `padding-bottom` on your `.video-container`.

**EDIT**

I just tried this:

```
.video-container {
  padding-bottom: 37.25%;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.video-container iframe {
  height: 100% !important;
}
```

And this what I get http://take.ms/Zh8eq
Let me know if this is what you're looking for.

**What my css looks like after applying yours in**

```
.video-container {
   position: relative;
   padding-bottom: 37.25%;
   padding-top: 25px;
   height: 0;
   margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.video-container iframe,
.video-container object,
.video-container embed {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 12.5%;
  width: 75%!important;
  height: 100%!important;
}
```

Comment: I did try that before posting here though but it'll just make things worse :(

Comment: I mean the video still there and video shrinks that I would see black on the sides but the gap is still there. I even tried taking out the padding too

Comment: ah! why didn't I think of trying margin-bottom instead of keep on trying padding! Let me try it...

Comment: somehow `margin-bottom` didn't work for me and if I just use your css there and delete the previous one this is what I get `https://remax.imprev.net/omc/viewImage.ipv?guid=a56844a2-b0e4-4ea2-ba14-8dd451c27149&fullsize=true` and I tried to view with both chrome and firefox though :(

Comment: you don't need to delete the previous style. just apply my patch above.

Comment: let me re-edit your post and show you what I have for the css then...because I applied your patch to the original css it's like this `https://remax.imprev.net/omc/viewImage.ipv?guid=135701b6-d8da-4ade-993b-caf37ccdbd35&fullsize=true`